# Rest- My get method doesn't return anything

Tags: php, slim

Im new using slim framework and Im trying to make a get. It doesn't return anything and it returns a code 200.

```
$app->get('/noticias',function ()use ($db,$app){
    try{
        $consulta = $db->prepare("select * from noticias");
        $consulta->execute();

        $resultados = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($resultados);
    }catch (Exception $ex){
        echo  'We cant show the news';
    }
});
```

[When I make a get this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Snel.png)

Do you know some tutorials of slim framework??

Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($resultados)` and see

Comment: For tutorials on slim see this [Slim Framework for beginners](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089720/2151290)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear if you're using Slim version 2 or 3. You should be using version 3.

The [documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/) has the [First Application Walkthrough](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html) tutorial that you should go through.